# Tkinter window opening after closing it (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

with the tkinter module whenever you close smth it opens a new window
hi guys, so for example here :

```
from tkinter import *
from pygame import *
from openai import *
window = Tk()
window.title("My app")
def ouvrir():
    Window2 = Toplevel()
def destroy():
    window.destroy()
def parametres_bouton():
    para = Toplevel()
window.geometry("800x300")
window.minsize(700, 400)
window.maxsize(1200, 900)
window.iconbitmap("Sans titre.ico")
window.config(background='#FF4800')
frame = Frame(window, bg='#FF4800')
label_window = Label(frame, text="Welcome To FRIEND", font=("Champion", 30), bg='#FF4800', fg='white')
label_window.pack(expand=YES)
label_2 = Label(frame, text="Options :", font=("Arial", 20), bg='#FF4800', fg='white')
label_2.pack(expand=YES)
frame.pack(expand=YES)
open = Button(frame, text="Ouvrir App", font=("MALBERG", 20), bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: [ouvrir(), destroy()])
open.pack(pady=30, fill=X, expand=YES)
settings = Button(frame, text="Parametres", font=("Arial", 20), bg='black', fg='white'         '')
settings.pack(pady=23, fill=X)
window.mainloop()
fenetre_2 = Tk()
fenetre_2.title("Appli")
frame_2 = Frame(bg="white")
fenetre_2_Label = Label(frame_2, text="Quel Action souhaitez vous faire", font="Arial", bg="#FF4800")
fenetre_2_Label.pack(pady=20, fill=X)
frame_2.pack(pady=20)
fenetre_2.config(background="white")
fenetre_2.geometry("900x600")
Achat = Button(frame_2, text="+ Ajouter Transactions", font="Okaso")
Achat.pack(pady=30, fill=X)
Compte = Button(frame_2, text="Compte en Banque", font="Okaso", fg="white", bg="black")
Compte.pack(pady=10, fill=X)
fenetre_2.mainloop()
settings = Tk()
frame_para = Frame(settings, bg='#FF4800')
settings.geometry("900x600")
settings_Label = Label(frame_para, text="Paramétres :", font="Arial",bg="black",fg='white')
settings.mainloop()
```

so here when i click on "ouvrir app" it opens a window but if close it the settings window im currently doing opens, anyone got a fix? ive been struggling for like a week so it would really mean

if its really messy just dont mind im kinda new to coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is built right now, you're opening `fenetre_2` after `window` is closed and `settings` after `fenetre_2` is closed. Generally, you should have only one `Tk` instance, use `Toplevel` for the other windows.

Also the command specified for your buttons should be a function (lambda or otherwise defined) and *not* function calls or a list. Create your windows inside the said functions:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def ouvrir():
    fenetre_2 = Toplevel()
    fenetre_2.title("Appli")
    frame_2 = Frame(fenetre_2, bg="white")
    fenetre_2_Label = Label(frame_2, text="Quel Action souhaitez vous faire", font="Arial", bg="#FF4800")
    fenetre_2_Label.pack(pady=20, fill=X)
    frame_2.pack(pady=20)
    fenetre_2.config(background="white")
    fenetre_2.geometry("900x600")
    Achat = Button(frame_2, text="+ Ajouter Transactions", font="Okaso")
    Achat.pack(pady=30, fill=X)
    Compte = Button(frame_2, text="Compte en Banque", font="Okaso", fg="white", bg="black")
    Compte.pack(pady=10, fill=X)
    fenetre_2.mainloop()

def parametres_bouton():
    settings = Toplevel()
    frame_para = Frame(settings, bg='#FF4800')
    frame_para.pack()
    settings.geometry("900x600")
    settings_Label = Label(frame_para, text="Paramétres :", font="Arial",bg="black",fg='white')
    settings_Label.pack()
    settings.mainloop()

window.geometry("800x300")

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack(expand=YES)

open_btn = Button(frame, text="Ouvrir App", font=("MALBERG", 20), bg='black', fg='white', command=ouvrir)
open_btn.pack(pady=30, fill=X, expand=YES)

settings = Button(frame, text="Parametres", font=("Arial", 20), bg='black', fg='white', command=parametres_bouton)
settings.pack(pady=23, fill=X)

window.mainloop()
```